# React, Render issue for index file

Tags: reactjs, render, react-dom

In my react project when i start it an error comes up that nothing was returned from render,
it has a problem with my index.js do you guys see any problems with the code.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './App.css';
import App from './App';


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Here is the error it throwsback
[ERROR IMAGE!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZZbMT.png)

any help at all apricated thanks!

App.js file (For Ref)
Here is the code for the app.js file incase this is needed thanks!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect,
} from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { Nav } from "./components/Navbar";
import Home from "./components/pages/Home";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
//Shop
import ProductPage from "./components/pages/ProductPage";
import Products from "./components/pages/Products";
import ShopProvider from "./context/shopContext";
import Cart from "./components/Cart";

//Shop
import { Provider as StyletronProvider, DebugEngine } from "styletron-react";
import { Client as Styletron } from "styletron-engine-atomic";

//SignUp
import SignUp from "./components/SignUp";
import Login from "./components/Login";

import { AuthProvider } from "./context/AuthContext";
import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";

import fire from "./config/fire";
import HeroSection from "./components/HeroSection";

import { Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";

//Debug const (for shop)
const debug =
  process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? void 0 : new DebugEngine();

//Engine
const engine = new Styletron();

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
const App = () => {

  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////




  function App() {
    return (
      <ShopProvider>
        <StyletronProvider value={engine} debug={debug} debugAfterHydration>
          <div className="page-container">
            {/* Router */}
            <Router>
              <Nav className="nav_desktop" />
              <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
              <Route path="/cart" exact component={Cart} />
              <Route path="/prints" exact component={Products} />
              <Route path="/product/:id" exact component={ProductPage} />
              <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
            </Router>

            <div className="app">

            </div>
            {/* Navbar */}
            <Router>

              <Nav className="nav_desktop" />
              <Nav />
              <Switch>
                <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
                <Route path="/cart" exact component={Cart} />
                <Route path="/product" exact component={Products} />
                <Route path="/product/:id" exact component={ProductPage} />
                <Route path="/signup" exact component={SignUp} />
              </Switch>
            </Router>
            <div className="content-wrap"></div>

            {/* Footer */}
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </StyletronProvider>
      </ShopProvider>
    );
  };
}

export default App;
```

Comment: show me your App. js, it seems the error is coming from the App.js

Comment: Updated there, code for app.js above

Comment: Your App.js component is created using const app = { } and using function App() {}. I think it should be created only using one of the two methods but not both

Comment: Is it just a typo on your question that you're returning a function from a function?

Comment: I suspect the outer arrow function App is unnecessary, please remove it and try again, let me know if it works

Answer (score 0):

From your code it looks like your `App` is returning wrongly. The error is because the render of `<App/>` is expecting JSX and instead you're returning a function. Seems like you've combined an arrow function from ES6 with the older `function` approach. Just use one of them. Like:

```
 const App = () => {
  return (
    <ShopProvider>
      <StyletronProvider value={engine} debug={debug} debugAfterHydration>
        <div className="page-container">
          {/* Router */}
          <Router>
            <Nav className="nav_desktop" />
            <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
            <Route path="/cart" exact component={Cart} />
            <Route path="/prints" exact component={Products} />
            <Route path="/product/:id" exact component={ProductPage} />
            <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
          </Router>

          <div className="app"></div>
          {/* Navbar */}
          <Router>
            <Nav className="nav_desktop" />
            <Nav />
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
              <Route path="/cart" exact component={Cart} />
              <Route path="/product" exact component={Products} />
              <Route path="/product/:id" exact component={ProductPage} />
              <Route path="/signup" exact component={SignUp} />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
          <div className="content-wrap"></div>

          {/* Footer */}
          <Footer />
        </div>
      </StyletronProvider>
    </ShopProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```